# Ajax loading data jQuery applied on data does not work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form in which i load inputs from other page using ajax and I have jQuery selectors on that inputs.. on ajax call the data loads but the jQuery which has been applied on that inputs does not work..

Comment: Very broad without actual details, but this is potentially a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: I would advice you to add some code you have tried into your question. It will increase the chances of getting an answer and reduce the chances of having your question flagged and closed.

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to rerun the listener after AJAX response or you can use **live()** method of JQuery to create the listener like this:-

```
$(selector).live( eventName, function(){
  // your code 
});
```